# Not able to style three element inside a flex box for small devices

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, styling

I am building my portfolio using react for the first time and i am stucked with formatting three element aligned using flex in case of small devices, in full screen everything is ok.

What i want to obtain is:
In full size(this case is ok): [image]

In small device what i am retrieving now is this:

[image]

What i want to obtain:

[image]

The image should be in the same row of the social icon, and i would like also that the text"Hello I'm Amedeo ... and the button" start vertically at the same position of the social icon.

The code used is this one:

HTML:

```
    function Intro() {
    return (
        <IntroStyled>
            <div className="item-1">
                <SocialMedia />
            </div>

            <div className="item-2">
                <h1>Hi, I'm Amedeo</h1>
                <p>Tech Entusiast</p>
                <Button />
            </div>
            <div className="item-3">
                <img src={Amedeo} alt="Amedeo_Image" />
            </div>
        </IntroStyled>
    );
}
```

CSS:

```
export const IntroStyled = styled.div`
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    //background-color: yellow;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .item-1 {
        order: 1;
    }
    .item-2 {
        order: 2;
    }
    .item-3 {
        order: 3;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        flex-direction: column;
        .item-1 {
            order: 1;
        }
        .item-2 {
            order: 3;
        }
        .item-3 {
            order: 2;
        }
    }
`;
```

Social Media icons:
HTML:

```
function SocialMedia() {
    return (
        //dimensione icone default =24
        <SocialMediaStyled>
            <a href="#" className="icon" target="_blank">
                <UilLinkedin size="24" />
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="icon" target="_blank">
                <UilInstagram size="24" />
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="icon" target="_blank">
                <UilGitHub size="24" />
            </a>
        </SocialMediaStyled>
    );
}
```

CSS:

```
export const SocialMediaStyled = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 100px;

    @media (max-width: 798px) {
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .icon {
        color: ${Colors.firstColor};
        margin-bottom: 10px;

        &:hover {
            color: ${Colors.firstColor_Alt};
        }
    }
`;
```

Could you help me please?
Thanks a lot
Amedeo

Edit:
After @antokhio comment I changed the code, now i am able to retrieve the expected result when i have a small device, as you can see in the below image:

[image]

But now image is in the wrong position when i am in full size.Order properties not working

[image]

New code:

HTML

```
function Intro() {
    return (
        <IntroStyled>
            <div className="intro_container">
                <div className="social_image_container">
                    <div className="item-1">
                        <SocialMedia />
                    </div>
                    <div className="item-3">
                        <img src={Amedeo} alt="Amedeo_Image" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="item-2">
                    <h1>Hi, I'm Amedeo</h1>
                    <p>Tech Entusiast</p>
                    <Button />
                </div>
            </div>
        </IntroStyled>
    );
}
```

CSS:

```
export const IntroStyled = styled.div`
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .intro_container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .social_image_container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .item-1 {
        order: 1;
    }
    .item-2 {
        order: 2;
    }
    .item-3 {
        order: 3;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .intro_container {
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: flex-start;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .item-1 {
            order: 1;
        }
        .item-2 {
            order: 3;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
        .item-3 {
            order: 2;
        }
    }
`;
```

Comment: Hi, that usually fixed with grids, if you want to keep it flex you have to add an extra flex eg: <div><div><social/><picture/></div><text/></div>

Comment: Hi @antokhio, i followed you suggestion, now in small device the result is correct, but i have a new problem in full size because order it is no longer respected.
I inserted new code in the post

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to achieve this:

1. **Put the divs `item-2` and `item-3` inside another styled component.**
   I named this new styled component `ProfileDescStyled`. This new
   inner styled component will handle the internal flex positioning of
   those two divs.
2. **Now put this `ProfileDescStyled` component inside a second div on the same level as `item-1`**. I gave this div a class name of `profile-desc-div`.

See the code below (I use ellipsis `...` to indicate parts of the code I didn't change and for brevity):

```
...
<IntroStyled> 
    <div className="item-1">
        <SocialMedia />
    </div>

    <div className="profile-desc-div">
        <ProfileDescStyled>
            <div className="item-2">
                <h1>Hi, I'm Amedeo</h1>
                <p>Tech Entusiast</p>
                {/* <Button /> */}
            </div>
            <div className="item-3">
                <img src={logo} alt="Amedeo_Image" width={500} />
            </div>
        </ProfileDescStyled>
    </div> 
</IntroStyled>
...
```

And the following steps are for the styled-component definitions from above:

3. **Remove the flex order properties for `item-2` and `item-3` in the `IntroStyled` definition.**
4. **Add in a flex order for the div `profile-desc-div` and assign the value of 2.**
5. **Remove the media query from the `IntroStyled` definition entirely.**
6. **In the `ProfileDescStyled` definition set `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to stack the elements within it vertically.**
7. **Lastly set add in a media query targeting just `item-2` and `item-3` and flipping their flex order properties as shown below.**

Like so:

```
export const IntroStyled = styled.div`
  ...

  .item-1 {
    order: 1;
  }

  .profile-desc-div {
    order: 2;
  }
`; 

export const ProfileDescStyled = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .item-2 {
      order: 3;
    }
    .item-3 {
      order: 2;
    }
  }
`;
```